Get not initialized Properties in Typescript
I'm trying to create a generic mapper, that can receive any object like types and interfaces, but also can receive a class, the problem is that most of the class that would receive doesn't have its properties initialized, something like this:
export class LoginDTO {
  @IsStringAndNotEmpty()
  email: string;

  @IsStringAndNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}

So when I try to execute this function
/**
 * Generic mapper to any object, type, interface or class
 * @param source Object to map properties
 * @param target Objet that gives the keys to map source properties
 * @returns must be a partial of target
 */
export function genericMapper<T>(source: any, target): T {
  const result = {} as T;

  try {
    const map = isClass(target) ? new target() : target;

    for (const key in map) {
      result[key] = source[key];
    }
  } catch { }

  return result;
}

It doesn't work because in Typescript the not initialized properties are not enumerable by default, but I can't initialize all the properties from all the DTOs in the whole project.
How can I get the unitialized properties of a class?
I tried to use Reflect.ownKeys(target.prototype) it doesn't work

Turn on useDefineForClassFields.
Then this code
export class LoginDTO {
  email!: string;
  password!: string;
}

will be compiled into
export class LoginDTO {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "email", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, "password", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
    }
}

Now you can enumerate properties:


class LoginDTO {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "email", {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: void 0
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "password", {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: void 0
    });
  }
}

const obj = new LoginDTO()
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj))
console.log(Object.keys(obj))



